# Fixing mollweide matplotlib projection contours

Tags: python, matplotlib, map-projections

I am having problems in making mollweide plots in the borders. The lines do not continue on the other side of the plot.[image]

Is there any way to fix this (the green curve should continue in the other side of the sphere )? I am using matplotlib projections. The code is plotting circles of known radius and known center but matplotlib is just cutting the lines. How I could solve this?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import getdist.plots as plots
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib
import scipy 
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import rc
from getdist import loadMCSamples
from getdist import loadMCSamples
from getdist import covmat
from getdist import MCSamples
from tabulate import tabulate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.projections.geo import GeoAxes
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class ThetaFormatterShiftPi(GeoAxes.ThetaFormatter):
    """Shifts labelling by pi
    Shifts labelling from -180,180 to 0-360"""
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        if x != 0:
            x *= -1
        if x < 0:
            x += 2*np.pi
        return GeoAxes.ThetaFormatter.__call__(self, x, pos)
        
        
mean1024 = [1,186,48]
sigma1024 = 30

x = np.linspace(-6.0, 6.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-6.0, 6.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    
l = (360.-mean1024[1])/(180/np.pi)
b = (mean1024[2])/(180/np.pi)
F = (X-l)**2 + (Y-b)**2 - (sigma1024/(180/np.pi))**2
F2 = (X-l)**2 + (Y-b)**2 - (2*sigma1024/(180/np.pi))**2
    

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10)) 
axs = plt.subplot(projection="mollweide")
axs.set_longitude_grid(45)
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ThetaFormatterShiftPi(45))
axs.set_latitude_grid(45)
axs.set_longitude_grid_ends(90)
plt.grid(True)
    
axs.contour(X,Y,F,[0], linewidths=1.5, colors = ['g'])
axs.contour(X,Y,F2,[0], linewidths=1.5, colors = ['g'])
    

plt.plot(l, b, '+', color = 'green')
    
box = axs.get_position()
axs.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height*0.8])
axs.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, -0.2))

fig.savefig('circles.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: I am reproducing your code in my environment, but the lines are only green, no black or blue. Is this situation correct? Do you have an expected output diagram?

Comment: Yes, I eliminated the blue and black, the problem is the green one since it is on the border of the map. Have no idea how to properly remap the missing part.